# CCNA OSPF Loopback as the router ID

Tags: cisco, ospf

FYI, I am studying for the CCNA and new to this.

The scenerio, 2 routers R1 and R2.
R1 Loopback IP as 192.168.0.1
R2 Loopback IP as 192.168.0.2
Using the loopback IP's as the router ID.
I provisioned R1 correctly, R2 is the problem. Instead of 192.168.0.2, i put it as 192.168.1.2
then added the router and network statement
router ospf 1
network 192.168.0.2 0.0.0.255 area 0

when I do show ip protocols, the router ID is 192.168.1.2 and the IP shows up under IP protocols

I did change the loopback IP to the correct IP of 192.1680.2
did no router ospf 1 and reprovisioned the network statement

The problem is, the old IP is still under the OSPF. How do I get rid of 192.168.1.2 without deleting the router and starting over?

```
R2#sh ip protocols 

Routing Protocol is "ospf 1"
  Outgoing update filter list for all interfaces is not set 
  Incoming update filter list for all interfaces is not set 
  Router ID 192.168.0.2
  Number of areas in this router is 2. 2 normal 0 stub 0 nssa
  Maximum path: 4
  Routing for Networks:
    10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 area 0
    192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
  Routing Information Sources:  
    Gateway         Distance      Last Update 
    192.168.0.1          110      00:09:37
    192.168.0.2          110      00:10:00
    192.168.1.2          110      00:48:30
  Distance: (default is 110)
```

Comment: Under the OSPF, shut it down and restart it.

Comment: Tried clear ip ospf process on R1 and R2

Comment: Sometimes you need to reboot the router.

Comment: Did you try `shutdown` and `no shutdown` under the OSPF router process?

Comment: Your output shows the Router ID has reflected the change as 192.168.0.2 --> "Router ID 192.168.0.2"

It looks like something is hanging onto the old source of 192.168.1.2 which makes it shows under Routing Information Sources. 

What does 'show ip ospf neighbors' and the 'show ip ospf database' say? Clearing the OSPF process should have cleared that out though.

Show us your OSPF configuration from R1 and R2.